# How to unflatten a JSON object and merge similar keys?

Tags: javascript, json, lodash

I have JSON in the given format :

```
{
"literature":
[
  {
   "category": "medical",
   "title": "med title",
   "abstract":"med abstract"
  },
  {
  "category": "medical",
  "title": "med title2",
  "abstract":"med abstract2"
  },
  {
  "category": "economics",
  "title": "eco title",
  "abstract":"eco abstract"
  },
  {
  "category": "science",
  "title": "sci title",
  "abstract":"sci abstract"
  }
]
  }
```

Desired Output :

```
{
"literature":
[
  {
"medical":
[
  {
   "title": "med title",
   "abstract":"med abstract"
  },
  {
  "title": "med title2",
  "abstract":"med abstract2"
  }
]
},
  {
  "economics":
[
  {
  "title": "eco title",
  "abstract":"eco abstract"
  }
 ]
},
  {
  "science":
   [
     {
  "title": "sci title",
  "abstract":"sci abstract"
     }
   ]
  }
]
}
```

I would convert the JSON to javascript object using `JSON.parse()` and then I would modify that object, making the category attribute as the key and merging the data inside the similar keys as illustrated above. I'm struck since the last three days, **Please help me out.**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create new object and use for...of to rewrite values

```js
const response = {
"literature":
[
  {
   "category": "medical",
   "title": "med title",
   "abstract":"med abstract"
  },
  {
  "category": "medical",
  "title": "med title2",
  "abstract":"med abstract2"
  },
  {
  "category": "economics",
  "title": "eco title",
  "abstract":"eco abstract"
  },
  {
  "category": "science",
  "title": "sci title",
  "abstract":"sci abstract"
  }
]
  }
  
function groupByCategory(items) {
 const grouped = {}
 for(const item of items) {
  grouped[item.category] = grouped[item.category] || [];
  const itemCopy = { ...item };
  delete itemCopy.category
  grouped[item.category].push(itemCopy)
 }
 
 console.log(grouped)
}

groupByCategory(response.literature)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for fast response. It solves my problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can be done easily with `reduce` like below

```js
const rawData = {"literature":[{"category":"medical","title":"medtitle","abstract":"medabstract"},{"category":"medical","title":"medtitle2","abstract":"medabstract2"},{"category":"economics","title":"ecotitle","abstract":"ecoabstract"},{"category":"science","title":"scititle","abstract":"sciabstract"}]}

function formatData(data) {
  return Object.keys(data).reduce((acc, key) => {
      acc[key] = data[key].reduce((groups, {category, ...rest}) => {
      if (!groups[category]) {
        groups[category] = [];
      }
      groups[category].push(rest);
      return groups;
    }, {});
    return acc;
  }, {});
}

const result = formatData(rawData);

console.log(result)
```